# App close on viewPager.setAdapter(adapter) in android 5.1 (just android 5.1)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using viewPager in my application, so that working properly in all android versions but doesn't work in android 5.1. When I try to set that app close without any exception or any error. I am trying to check in most of android so that working in android 4.4.2 and later but in android 5.1 not working and app close without any error.
have you any solution for that?
I attached my code below.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    MyPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    if (viewPager != null)
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    if (mTabLayout != null) {
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        for (int i = 0; i < mTabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = mTabLayout.getTabAt(i);
            if (tab != null)
                tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
        }

        mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).getCustomView().setSelected(true);
    }

}


private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;

    private final String[] mTabsTitle = {"Scan", "History","Setting"};

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public View getTabView(int position) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity2.this).inflate(R.layout.toolbar, null);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setImageResource(mTabsIcons[position]);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        switch (pos) {

            case 0:
                return FirstFragment.newInstance(1);
            case 1:
                return SecondFragment.newInstance(2);
            case 2:
                return ThirdFragment.newInstance(3);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mTabsTitle[position];
    }

}
```

Comment: error logs please...

Comment: thanks dear Prajwal, I found that problem. I remove android:backgroundTint from floatingActionButton then my problem solved.

Comment: Thats because background:tint is not supported on lower versions... :)